# How to login on twitter and get random users followers using jsoup?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsoup

I am using this code to log in , but getting an error.

```
 String url = "https://twitter.com/sessions";
    String title = "https://twitter.com";

Map<String, String> cont = new HashMap<String, String>();
cont.put("session[username_or_email]", "omurbek_jk");
cont.put("session[password]", "put_your_password_here");
//  cont.put("authenticity_token","ad09712240d123e04ed63aa46bf65aa0fb1b6ad4");
cont.put("scribe_log", "");

cont.put("redirect_after_login", "/");
//   cont.put("authenticity_token","ad09712240d123e04ed63aa46bf65aa0fb1b6ad4");
cont.put("remember_me", "1");

Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(url)
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .userAgent("Mozilla")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .execute();

System.out.println("COOKIES: " + loginForm.cookies());
System.out.println("Header Values: " + loginForm.statusCode());
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
        .data(cont)
        .referrer("https://twitter.com/")
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
        .post();
```

And it prints:

```
COOKIES: {fm=0, _twitter_sess=BAh7...
Header Values: 200
Login on Twitter
```

Comment: Error/stacktrace missing. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a little bit more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you limited to using JSOUP? Session management and complex web-queries can be hard with it. There are some more high-level frameworks which, for example, can handle sessions and cookies automatically, or allow a JQuery-style parsing of the received webpage.